# Making more room for Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, partition, windows, disk

Yesterday I shrank a volume, and installed Ubuntu on it because I wanted to dual boot, I'm dual-booting Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04 on the same drive.

I have just noticed that I might need more space for my workflow and I want to shrink it further.

I used Windows Disk Management to shrink a volume to be able to install Ubuntu.

I wanted to ask those who have done this, will this give me problems? Will Ubuntu use the new space?

Furthermore, considering that the free space will now be allocated before the OS I'm kinda worried I might break something.

This is the output for `parted -l` on the drive in which I want to make more space:

```
Model: ATA WDC WDS500G2B0A (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      17,4kB  16,8MB  16,8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 2      16,8MB  393GB   393GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 3      393GB   393GB   538MB   fat32        EFI System Partition          boot, esp
 4      393GB   500GB   107GB   ext4
```

I want to add some space from the ntfs partition to my system.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us more details. What is your partitioning scheme? What partitions do you have (show us the output of `sudo parted -l`)? Which one do you want to shrink? Which one do you want to extend? How will you shrink it? How will you extend it? What does Windows have to do with any of this?

Comment: @tendon You're right sorry Tendon. I've updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your NTFS (Windows) and your EXT4 (Linux) Partitions don't lie back-to-back on the disk, you won't win anything, unless you first shrink the NTFS partition, move the EFI partition to be right after the end of that partition, then move the EXT4 to right after the end of that, and then extend the ext4 partition into the free space that's then at the end of all this.

That's a hassle. If I'm frank, I'd just backup my data from linux, remove the linux partition, install Ubuntu using the alternative installer ([see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239264/is-it-possible-to-setup-lvm-with-the-ubuntu-20-04-graphical-installer)) to use LVM as partitioning scheme.

That way, you can just add arbitrarily positioned physical volumes later on to extend your available space on your Linux, without having to worry whether the volumes lie contiguously on disk/SSD, or even on the same device.

Comment: Thank you a lot!! I'll do just that! Disk partitioning is a topic I haven't quite mastered.